# how to enable Micrometer metrics for redis cache

Tags: java, caching, quarkus

In my quarkus application, I use redis as the backend, and would like to know some metrics.
However, https://quarkus.io/guides/cache seems only support in-memory cache (caffeine) ?
is metrics on redis-based cache supported? Any way to enable it?

Comment: I am pretty sure we don't have this feature, so it would be best if you opened an issue on GitHub asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the redis cache: https://quarkus.io/guides/cache-redis-reference
together with the Micrometer extension: https://quarkus.io/guides/telemetry-micrometer.

The cache uses the `quarkus-redis-client` which is instrumented with Micrometer.